# Play 2nd DLC without 1st

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

While browsing some questions here about the max level, I started to wonder if its possible to play the 2nd DLC without owing the 1st.

The reason for my question is the level cap, which was 40 in the main game and has been increased to 45 with the first DLC. The 2nd DLC then increased it to 55. The area for the 2nd DLC is from level 45 to 55. Theoretically it is possible to kill the enemys there with only level 40.

Yet I am not sure if the game allows it. So is it possible to play the 2nd DLC without owning the 1st?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Ubisoft Offical Store, the [description of DLC 2](https://store.ubi.com/uk/assassin-s-creed--origins---the-curse-of-the-pharaohs/5a9d712c88a7e30993e580c1.html) reads:

> This is extra content for a game which need the game to run.

There is no mention of needing another DLC in order to buy and use this one. The same sentence is present on the [page of DLC 1](https://store.ubi.com/uk/assassin-s-creed-origins----the-hidden-ones/5a5e11ee88a7e3b6351233e3.html).

In those descriptions, there is no detail about what are the level caps and new abilities introduced by the expansions, as when they were published on the shop, this information wasn't avalaible to players.

So according to all this information, I think you can play DLC 2 without owning DLC 1.